# How do I edit/undo/remove an entry from .svnignore in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

This seems like a simple problem, but I can't figure out how to edit the svn-ignore list from Eclipse.  Strangely I couldn't find how to do so on a web search or on stackoverflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Right click on the folder
2. Team meanu → Show Properties
3. On the properties tab, click the SVN:ignore line, and edit the value
4. Commit the folder

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a '.svnignore' file. There is the svn:ignore property of a directory, specifying things to ignore therein. As per another answer, this property can be edited eclipse via Team->Properties.